# How can I solve a attribute error in llama_index in google colab

Tags: python, attributeerror, llama-index

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ask_ai()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/indices/loading.py in load_indices_from_storage(storage_context, index_ids, **kwargs)
62     if index_ids is None:
63         logger.info("Loading all indices.")
---> 64         index_structs = storage_context.index_store.index_structs()
65     else:
66         logger.info(f"Loading indices with ids: {index_ids}")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'index_store'

I am doing this in google colab I tried to run it newly but same error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show some piece of code [MRE] so we can help. See welcome [tour] and [ask].